# Complex MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have the data:

```
id    item      value
1       4         10
2       4         30
3       5         10
4       4         30
5       5         40
```

First I want to get a result which all the item is 4

```
1       4         10
2       4         30
4       4         30
```

Then I want choose the biggest value , if more than one get them all.

```
2       4         30
4       4         30
```

And choose the random one.

```
2       4         30
```

or

```
4       4         30
```

I want do this in one SQL, How can I do that ?

Comment: `Extremely complex` ? You made my day ! BTW anything you tried so far ?

Comment: its too complex for earthlings , u need to post this on inter galactic cyber forum for more intelligent beings to solve  :)

Comment: Still, lots of people get it wrong :-(

Comment: well… I am new for mysql , thanks for everyone , finally I figure it out. thanks

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/040ff/3

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table1 t
LEFT JOIN table1 t2
ON t.item=t2.item
  AND t.value<t2.value
WHERE t.item=4 and t2.value IS NULL
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT item,MAX(value) max_value FROM my_table GROUP BY item) y 
    ON y.item = x.item 
   AND y.max_value = x.value 
 WHERE x.item = 4 
 ORDER 
    BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT id, item, value FROM table1 WHERE item = 4 GROUP BY id ORDER BY value DESC, rand() LIMIT 1;
```

Edit: change the SQL Thx @Alex for pointing my mistake. Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/040ff/26)

Comment: so this query can return `id=1` if posted sample of data is in use. which is wrong. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/040ff/5

Comment: This result is indeterminate - not quite the same as random!

Comment: No it is not. Check your fiddle. You are cheater ;-) :-) you don't use `LIMIT 1` in your fiddle. that is why you think it works. but if you will apply `LIMIT 1` it will always return id=2 (don't ask me why).

Comment: @Alex No it's just the randomness, here is a screen where you can clearly see it working. http://i.imgur.com/48nhI2K.png

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.id, t.item, t.value 
FROM my_table t
WHERE t.item = 4
  AND t.value = (SELECT MAX(ti.value) FROM my_table ti WHERE t.item = ti.item)
ORDER BY rand() 
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95517/6

Thanks for the great answer, But many of this use join , after communicate with my colleague I got a another answer without join.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE 
  value = (SELECT max(value) FROM table1 
       WHERE item = 4)
  AND item = 4
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1;
```